# Where does Azure Cosmos DB store data?

Tags: azure, storage, azure-cosmosdb

Where does Azure Cosmos DB store data? Is it stored in Azure Table or Blob Storage, or something else?
I have looked through the Docs from MS and I do not see this explained anywhere.

Comment: Why do you care? :)

Comment: Why you want to know can be relevant to properly answer your question. e.g. If you need the answer for a particular use-case or if it depends on something. It also helps to see if you are suffering from an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Thanks Worthwelle. I am just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure we can't really answer this question beyond what [Microsoft tells us](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/faq#how-does-azure-cosmos-db-support-various-data-models-such-as-keyvalue-columnar-document-and-graph):

> Key/value (table), columnar, document, and graph data models are all natively supported because of the ARS (atoms, records, and sequences) design that Azure Cosmos DB is built on. Atoms, records, and sequences can be easily mapped and projected to various data models. The APIs for a subset of models are available right now (SQL, MongoDB, Table, and Gremlin) and others specific to additional data models will be available in the future.

> Azure Cosmos DB has a schema agnostic indexing engine capable of automatically indexing all the data it ingests without requiring any schema or secondary indexes from the developer. The engine relies on a set of logical index layouts (inverted, columnar, tree) which decouple the storage layout from the index and query processing subsystems. Cosmos DB also has the ability to support a set of wire protocols and APIs in an extensible manner and translate them efficiently to the core data model (1) and the logical index layouts (2) making it uniquely capable of supporting more than one data model natively.

But the comments to your question are still relevant. If Microsoft does their job right, you shouldn't need to care how or where it's stored. And if you feel that how you proceed building an app is determined on how the data is stored, you probably need to ask a different question. But if you only wanted to know out of curiosity, then here you go.